# Why is my Xcode 10.1 Playground not running code?

Tags: ios, performance, macos-high-sierra, xcode10.1

So I have a Macbook pro 2011 with High Sierra and Xcode 10.1 and starting last week, playgrounds stopped working for me.

When I run ANY kind of code, even print("Hello") the status bar (Activity viewer) on top shows "launching simulator" for 3-5 seconds and then nothing happens, I got no answer on the results sidebar (panel on the right) or the panel in the bottom where code gets executed.

I know its an old computer but I am learning Swift and I am not able to buy a more recent computer or rent a "Mac in Cloud".

I read some forums and they recommended to restart Xcode, to take the files off the Desktop but  it didn't work.

I was using an online compiler but most tools are not up to date so I cant execute arc4random_uniform() or stuff like that.

Do any of you have a suggestion? Please, kindly help.

Miguel

Comment: Actually arc4random_uniform is outdated.

Comment: Ok so I’ve got the same setup. Did you toggle the Run button at the bottom of the playground code?

Comment: Hi! Yes, I did toggled the run button and that didnt work, toggled back and still not working.

Comment: Try this: quit Xcode, delete _Library/Developer/CoreSimulator_. Now launch Xcode again. See if that helps.

Comment: Hi Matt! Thanks for the advice, tried it but still didnt work :(

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. But I think I've solved it. Here's how:

1. [Try to change platform (from iOS to macOS or vice versa)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpmO9.png)
2. Try to create a new Playground
3. Switch from "Automatically run" to "Manually run" (by holding down a play        icon at the bottom)
4. If none of this helped try to reload you Mac and contact Apple Support.